# What do the orange bat head icons indicate in the AR challenges?

Tags: batman-arkham-knight

The AR challenges are a welcome addition. A lot more fun than the challenge maps. Getting the three stars for each will be fun. But when you go over the three star score, you can get orange bat heads the further away you go.

[image: the orange bat head icons]

**What are these for and what purpose do they serve?**

Comment: They are called "Rival Points" but what they do I'm not sure. I assume (though may be wrong) that they are just a way to compare your performance past the three star rating but I'm not sure (hence comment not answer). I've certainly found no use for them after ~15 hours gameplay.

Comment: P.S. Good job on the mission. +7 Rival points is pretty good I'd reckon (mostly I've got one or two, most I have is 5 on any mission).

Comment: It's actually relatively easy to score well in One Man Army IMO. As long as you can maintain your multiplier to the end, you'll do well.

Comment: That's the theory... In practice I usually end up getting hit by something or missing a couple of shots in a row. The one I have got a lot of rival points in is Tower Defence which is a relatively standard combat one and I just got my combo bonus up to 70 odd. I was slightly amused that I missed the last guy so I got a perfect freeflow up until the last guy and then a four hit combo. :(

Comment: I just started the game last night and I noticed that at the main menu you can go to the leaderboard and set one of your friends as a "rival."  Seeing how these things are called "rival points" we must assume that the two are related in some way.  My guess would be simply for comparison's sake, but who knows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Rival Points contribute to your Gotham's Greatest leaderboard score - example below.

[image: Gotham's Greatest leaderboard page]

As you can see, I currently have 5 Rival Points, which brings my total to 91. This is presumably for tie-breaking purposes, on the main leaderboard - anyone who has completed 100% of the story, 100% of the Most Wanted content, and all of the AR missions would otherwise have the same score. This allows some differentiation.

Comment: Hopefully there will be further use for these points.  This is the only way they can further distinguish how well someone does in a challenge.  3 stars is not enough to gauge how well you do.

Comment: Yeah. I guess it's just the best way to generate a single number for the varying types of score (in seconds, totals, ratings, etc)